# Expo Managed Workflow Failing to Build in Fastlane Step (Metro Config Error)

Tags: react-native, expo, microsoft-metro

Trying to build my React Native Expo Managed Workflow app with EAS, but I keep getting this error: [image]

There is a hint that something may be going wrong initially, though. It throws me this warning before building: [image]

This is my `metro.config.js` file.

Comment: Go to the build details link and scroll to the bottom. You should be able to download logs there. They always give me the insight I need to debug. In the single case it has not, I had to destruct my app component by component and reupload to eas to find the issue.